# Advantages of Scala's type system

Tags: scala, types

I am exploring the Scala language. One claim I often hear is that Scala has a *stronger* type system than Java. By this I think what people mean is that:

- `scalac` rejects certain buggy programs which `javac` will compile happily, only to cause a runtime error.
- Certain invariants can be encoded in a Scala program such that the compiler won't let the programmer write code that violates the condition.

Am I right in thinking so?

Comment: Java won't let you compile "buggy programs" any more than Scala does; however, Scala *allows* many more constructs to be [safely] expressed -- and generally in a much easier method -- than Java. Scala still "suffers" from type erasure, though.

Comment: @pst: Yes, it will. `String[] strings = {"foo"}; Object[] objects = strings; objects[0] = new Object();` will compile just fine in java and then throw a NPE at runtime. The equivalent scala-code will not compile.

Comment: @sepp2k I think it is an `ArrayStoreException` that gets thrown, not an NPE.

Comment: @pst: I think the whole point of having a static type system is to automatically derive certain properties of a program without actually running it. So I am expecting `scalac` to analyze the input program and accept it only if certain class of errors are not present.

Comment: Yes, of course. I don't know why I said NPE.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

The main advantage of the Scala Type system is not so much being *stronger* but rather being far *richer* (see "[The Scala Type System](https://web.archive.org/web/20110122231742/http://programming-scala.labs.oreilly.com/ch12.html)").
(Java can define some of them, and implement others, but Scala has them built-in).
See also [The Myth Makers 1: Scala's "Type Types"](http://www.artima.com/forums/flat.jsp?forum=106&thread=245183), commenting [Steve Yegge's blog post](http://steve-yegge.blogspot.com/2008/06/rhinos-and-tigers.html), where he "disses" Scala as "Frankenstein's Monster" because "there are type types, and type type types".

- Value type classes (useful for reasonably small data structures that have value semantics) used instead of primitives types (Int, Doubles, ...), with implicit conversion to "Rich" classes for additional methods.
- [Nonnullable type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1522367/library-support-for-scalas-notnull-trait)
- [Monad types](http://debasishg.blogspot.com/2008/03/monads-another-way-to-abstract.html)
- Trait types (and the [mixin composition](http://debasishg.blogspot.com/2006/04/scala-compose-classes-with-mixins.html) that comes with it)
- Singleton object types (just define an 'object' and you have one),
- [Compound types](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/110) (intersections of object types, to express that the type of an object is a subtype of several other types),
- [Functional types](http://www.codecommit.com/blog/scala/scala-for-java-refugees-part-6) (`(type1, …)=>returnType` syntax),
- [Case classes](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/107) (regular classes which export their constructor parameters and which provide a recursive decomposition mechanism via pattern matching),
- [Path-dependent types](http://programming-scala.labs.oreilly.com/ch12.html#PathDependentTypes) (Languages that let you nest types provide ways to refer to those type paths),
- [Anonymous types](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/133) (for defining anonymous functions),
- [Self types](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/124) (can be [used for instance in Trait](http://markthomas.info/blog/?p=92)),
- [Type aliases](http://davetron5000.github.com/scala-style/naming_conventions/type_aliases.html), along with:
- [package object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1605976/using-type-aliases-to-java-enums) (introduced in 2.8)
- [Generic types](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/113) (like Java), with a [type parameter annotation mechanism](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/129) to control the subtyping behavior of generic types,

  - Covariant generic types: The annotation `+T` declares type `T` to be used only in covariant positions. `Stack[T]` is a subtype of `Stack[S]` if `T` is a subtype of `S`.
  - Contravariant generic types: `-T` would declare `T` to be used only in contravariant positions.
- Bounded generic types (even though [Java supports some part of it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1751275/are-there-any-plans-for-java-to-add-generic-collection-covariance)),
- [Higher kinded types](https://blogs.atlassian.com/2013/09/scala-types-of-a-higher-kind/), which allow one to express more advanced type relationships than is possible with Java Generics,
- [Abstract types](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/105) (the alternative to generic type),
- [Existential types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292274/what-is-an-existential-type) (used [in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031042/scalas-existential-types) like the Java wildcard type),
- [Implicit types](http://www.codecommit.com/blog/scala/scala-for-java-refugees-part-6) (see "[The awesomeness of Scala is implicit](http://technically.us/code/x/the-awesomeness-of-scala-is-implicit)",
- [View bounded types](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/130), and
- [Structural types](http://langexplr.blogspot.com/2007/07/structural-types-in-scala-260-rc1.html), for specifing a type by specifying characteristics of the desired type (duck typing).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed write up. I will read the linked articles to get a better understanding.

Comment: Note to self: see also my old answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2682673/what-compromises-scala-made-to-run-on-jvm/2682962#2682962

Comment: Note to self: with implicit and the new 2.8 context bound, pattern like "Type Class" are easily defined and used: http://dcsobral.blogspot.com/2010/06/implicit-tricks-type-class-pattern.html

Comment: Note to self: beware of structural typing used with the "pimping my library" pattern: there can be severe performance issues. See http://www.scala-notes.org/2010/06/avoid-structural-types-when-pimping-libraries/

Comment: I boldly started to consider this a Community wiki page (it should be!) and added higher kinded types.

Comment: @Lii good addition (as long as it doesn't convert that post in CW mode!)

Comment: First link in answer is broken

Comment: @AvremelKaminetzky Thank you. I have restored that first link.

Answer (score 17):

The main safety problem with Java relates to variance. Basically, a programmer can use incorrect variance declarations that may result in exceptions being thrown at run-time in Java, while Scala will not allow it.

In fact, the very fact that Java's `Array` is co-variant is already a problem, since it allows incorrect code to be generated. For instance, as exemplified by [sepp2k](https://stackoverflow.com/users/149392/sepp2k):

```
String[] strings = {"foo"};
Object[] objects = strings;
objects[0] = new Object();
```

Then, of course, there are raw types in Java, which allows all sort of things.

Also, though Scala has it as well, there's casting. Java API is rich in type casts, and there's no idiom like Scala's `case x: X => // x is now safely cast`. Sure, one case use `instanceof` to accomplish that, but there's no incentive to do it. In fact, Scala's `asInstanceOf` is intentionally verbose.

These are the things that make Scala's type system stronger. It is also much richer, as [VonC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6309/vonc) shows.

Comment: Finally, an answer which is more "on topic" than mine "more general" list ;) +1

Comment: you answered the original question accurately, but VonC answered a slightly different question elaborately. I am voting his answer as the correct one, but your answer is much appreciated too. Hope you don't mind missing out on the reputation points.

Comment: @binil Not at all. VonC's answer is great, even if he really doesn't need the extra reputation... ;-)