# What does this piece of code mean in scala?

Tags: scala, syntax

```
def func(arg: String => Int): Unit = {
    // body of function
}
```

I mean this fragment:
String => Int

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in [Advantages of Scala’s Type System](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3112725/advantages-of-scalas-type-system), it is a **Functional type**.

The article [Scala for Java Refugees Part 6: Getting Over Java](http://www.codecommit.com/blog/scala/scala-for-java-refugees-part-6) describes this syntax in its section "Higher-Order Functions".

```
def itrate(array:Array[String], fun:(String)=>Unit) = {
  for (i <- 0 to (array.length - 1)) {    // anti-idiom array iteration
    fun(array(i))
  }
}

val a = Array("Daniel", "Chris", "Joseph", "Renee")
iterate(a, (s:String) => println(s))
```

> See?  The syntax is so natural you almost miss it.
>   Starting at the top, we look at the **type of the fun parameter** and we see the `(type1, …)=>returnType` syntax which indicates a functional type.
>   In this case, fun will be a functional which takes a single parameter of type String and returns Unit (effectively void, so anything at all).
>   Two lines down in the function, we see the syntax for actually invoking the functional.  fun is treated just as if it were a method available within the scope, the call syntax is identical.
>   Veterans of the C/C++ dark-ages will recognize this syntax as being reminiscent of how function pointers were handled back-in-the-day.
>   The difference is, no memory leaks to worry about, and no over-verbosity introduced by too many star symbols.

---

In your case: `def func(arg: String => Int): Unit`, `arg` would be a function taking a String and returning an Int.

Answer (score 9):

**Short answer**

Its a function that receives a String and returns a Int

**Long answer**

In Scala, functions are first class citizens. That means you can store them in variables or (like in this case) pass them around as arguments.

This is how a function literal looks like

```
() => Unit
```

This is a function that receives no arguments and returns Unit (java's equivalent to void).

This would be a function that receives a String as a parameter and returns an Int:

```
(String) => Int
```

Also, scala let's you drop the parenthesis as a form of syntactic sugar, like in your example. The preceding `arg:` is just the name of the argument.

Inside `func` you would call the function received (`arg`) like this:

```
val result = arg("Some String") // this returns a Int
```

Comment: You mean `arg` is a function that ... . Right?

Answer (score 4):

You might also see it written (perhaps by a decompiler) as

```
def func(arg: Function1[String, Int]): Unit = {
    // body of function
}
```

They are precisely equivalent.